# java efficient concatenation of multiple lists

Tags: java, list, union

I often find myself writing code that builds a List out of multiple sublists. As a simple example suppose you have a List that needs to be validated to a List. One way to write this (imperatively) would be:

```
import static com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList;

import java.util.List;

public class Product {

    private String name;
    private int height;

    public static List<String> validateList(List<Product> products) {
        List<String> result = newArrayList();
        valideListSize(products, result);
        for (Product product : products) {
            product.validate(result);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static void valideListSize(List<Product> products,
            List<String> result) {
        if (products.size() > 1000) {
            result.add("List too large");
        }
    }

    private void validate(List<String> result) {
        if (name.length() > 30) {
            result.add("Name contains too many characters");
        }
        if (height > 40) {
            result.add("Product too high");
        }
    }

}
```

However for simplicity/maintenance/reuse I don't like to couple the logic of validating a single Product to adding the list of validation results to another existing list. I also think mutating a parameter can lead to more hard to debug code. So I prefer a more functional style. Currently I would typically write like this (using newArrayList from Google Guava):

```
import static com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList;
import static java.util.Collections.emptyList;
import static java.util.Collections.singletonList;

import java.util.List;

public class Product {

    private String name;
    private int height;

    public static List<String> validateList(List<Product> products) {
        List<String> result = newArrayList();
        result.addAll(valideListSize(products));
        for (Product product : products) {
            result.addAll(product.validate());
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static List<String> valideListSize(List<Product> products) {
        if (products.size() > 1000) {
            return singletonList("List too large");
        }
        return emptyList();
    }

    private List<String> validate() {
        List<String> result = newArrayList();
        if (name.length() > 30) {
            result.add("Name contains too many characters");
        }
        if (height > 40) {
            result.add("Product too high");
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

This creates many small arraylists with a very short lifespan, many of which will typically be empty (no validation errors).
Will this kind of code be inefficient in practice or is it ok to use this style in a production environment?
Is there a more efficient way (perhaps using Guava) of doing what I want while still keeping the code clean and easy to read and conform to Java best practices?

What would you as a professional Java developer do?

EDIT: see my answer on first comment why I prefer the second way. I prefer code maintainability/readability over premature optimization, but because I see this kind of pattern a lot in daily programming I am wondering if there is a simple way that is at least as clean.
What about using some kind of joined list view, e.g. Iterables.concat? Or does that also create many intermediate classes?

Comment: May I ask why do you need multiple lists for the validations. Can you not store all validations in a single list? That way you could avoid creating multiple lists as yourself mentioned in the question.

Comment: You are right, I actually have only one list in my first code example. I'm just being perfectionistic here: I was thinking more of having the cleanest/simplest design. What I don't like about that single-product validation method:
 * adding to an existing list is not a concern of validating one product
 * no guarantee that the method e.g. removes anything from the list making the probability for bugs higher
 * the method signature is simpler so easier to understand (side-effect free) and document if it has no list parameter
 * easier reuse of single Product validation

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to efficiently accomplish this with a [Disjoint-set data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure), also called a union-find data structure.  There are several implementations available online, e.g. [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/Implementationofdisjointsetdatastructure.htm).

Comment: Cool thank you! I've seen this before but didn't think of it here. However it also feels a bit overengineered for daily programming tasks.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question: Java does a good job with performance even when creating many new lists inside the single-product validate method. I timed validating a list of 300000 Products for 10 times (after warmup).

The first implementation where one Arraylist is passed around takes 275ms. Using a LinkedList it takes 300ms.
The second implementation where may intermediate ArrayLists are created takes 760ms. Using a LinkedList takes 580ms. Using Guava's ImmutableList builder takes 1150ms.

So I guess I'll simply keep using my second method (perhaps using a LinkedList for small lists that don't require random access).